# Search collection of name using solr

Tags: arrays, solr

I am beginner developer to know about solr technologies. Today, i am trying to develope autocomplete using solr technologies. I have been installed solr in my laptop. From my research about solr, solr required number of object to be their data collection.

Ex :

```
[ { id:1, name:"Stackoverflow" }, { id:2, name:"Stackofchange" }, .....]
```

My question, Could solr technologies support array of name to be their data collection ?

Ex:

```
["Stackoverflow", "Stackofchange", .....]
```

So, i have not to convert array of name to be array of object.

If solr support array of name to be their data collection. 
Could let me know how i create schema.xml on my solr admin ? I have been trying to create my schema.xml using multivalues however i always failed to import data with simple data json

```
{ id:1, name:["Stackoverflow", "Stackofchange"] }
```

This is exception i got

> Exception writing document id 1 to the index; possible analysis error:
>   cannot change DocValues type from SORTED to SORTED_SET for field
>   "name"

Thanks.

*Please let me know if i am misunderstanding about solr technologies*

Answer (score 0):

To store/index array values we need to set `multivalued="true"` for field definition in schema file.

field defintion for `name` field should like below

```
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

After you modify schema file, restart Solr and reindex documents. then you will see

```
{ id:1, name:["Stackoverflow", "Stackofchange"] }
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response

My next question, 

Could we search string from field "name" in solr.

Ex : 
I want to search string with key "flow", the result i hope is ["Stackoverflow"]

Comment: you can. should specify field name with query string. ex: `q=name:flow` this will match word `flow` not `stackoverflow` for that you should use n-gram tokenizer. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-N-GramTokenizer

Comment: Thanks, i have been trying to add NGramTokenizerFactory in schema.xml. I have been searching using `q=name:flow` however i get `"numFound":0`. I hope with `{ id:1, name:["Stackoverflow", "Stackofchange"] }` and i search `q=name:flow` then i get `["Stackoverflow"]`